# Winforms application: Dependency issues for different versions of dependency dll

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

In our production environment, there are a number of separate winform applications and a "gridview.dll" in the same directory.  I cannot change this fact.

Recently I created a new application using a new version of the gridview.dll.  I can't update the existing gridview.dll on the box because it will break existing winform applications.  Since the .dll's shared the same name, I renamed the newer "gridview2.dll".

This works fine on my local machine, but for some odd reason fails on the production box.  Giving an error message that it could not load the older "gridview.dll".

How can I workaround this issue?

Comment: where is the file located?GAC?other directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using redirection in the config, and testing to see if the newer version will serve the purpose of both, so that you don't need the old DLL.  You will have to determine the exact versions of each, the true assembly name(sometimes the filename but sometimes not), and the publicKeyToken.

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="gridview" publicKeyToken="?????"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Still seem to be having problems.  Might have a red herring on my hands.  I placed the winform executable and new .dll in a sub directory on its own.  Still run into the same "could not load file or assembly" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install both gridviews in the GAC, and not in the application folder, it might work - each process will get the gridview it wants based on the version.

This will work if the gridviews have a strong name.

You might have to help .NET with explicit redirections. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_Specifyingassemblybindinginconfigurationfiles). Try it without redirections first.

Answer (score -2):

The recommended solution to this sort of problem is assemblies.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173099.aspx 
This will allow each application to point to a different version of the dll and to have both versions available on the system at once.
Alternatively you could use a private assembley with the new application and have a separate instance of the dll for the new application.
Unfortunately, it is kind of heavy-weight, but it will allow each application to have a separate context in which to resolve dlls.

Comment: You should probably put what exactly you are referencing into the content of your answer. I don't think your first sentence really explains anything.